# Challenge Error: An external object with the API name Phone__x does not exist or it does not have a field with the API name 'UUID__c'

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-connect, lightning-design-system, trailhead

I am working on a Trail-head challenge "[Lightning Connect](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/lightning_connect/lightning_connect_integrate)" where i need to configure a external data source sync the external objects and need to create a Indirect Lookup to User Object.
I have configured everything but not able to proceed further.

Below is the Tasks to config in ORG:

[image]

Error says that Object and the field is not prasent but i have them in my Org, below the screenshot of my org external object:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

try to edit the api name of your phone external object, remove your namespace prefix. The external object Phone must have an api 'Phone__x' and your custom field UUID api must be 'UUID__c'.